# How to record video of a filtered UIImageView in Swift?

Tags: swift, video, uiimageview, swift4, video-recording

I have my camera's output going through a UIImageView's image so that a filter effect can be applied to it in real time. How do I capture the video output that I'm seeing in real time? I want to start recording for as long as I want, then stop the recording and have the resulting video stored somewhere temporary so that I can later save it to my camera roll.

My real issue that I'm unfamiliar with is capturing the UIImageView as video.

For example, I can see the video output with my function that is changing the UIImageView:

```
func captureOutput(_ output: AVCaptureOutput, didOutput sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, from connection: AVCaptureConnection){

        if(captureOutput){

            let pixelBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer)
            let cameraImage = CIImage(cvPixelBuffer: pixelBuffer!)


            image = UIImage(ciImage: cameraImage)

            if let ciImage = image?.ciImage {

                image = filterImage(with:ciImage, filterDeg:hueDeg)

                var orientation = UIImageOrientation.right

                if(isFrontCamera){

                    orientation = UIImageOrientation.leftMirrored

                }

                image = UIImage(cgImage: (image?.cgImage)!, scale: 1.0, orientation: orientation)

            }

            DispatchQueue.main.async(){

                imageView!.image = image
            }

        }

    }
```

But how can I start actually recording the UIImageView as saved video?

Comment: I just want to mention that I have since moved past this and successfully recorded video, but my code is radically different and using Metal. I don't "record" the image view. It was beyond my understanding then.